# "myList.Count" is less then the amount of elements inside the list

Tags: c#, list, count

I have a task to write a program that takes some numbers and `step` as input.
 Then it must make a sequence of binary representation of those numbers and destroy bits at positions `1`, `1*step`, `2*step`, `3*step`... 
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class BitKiller
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int
            amountNumbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),
            step = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),
            counter = 0,
            number = 0
        ;
        int[] 
            numBin= new int[8],
            numbers = new int[amountNumbers]
        ;
        var sequence = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < amountNumbers; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            numBin = ToBin(numbers[i]);
            sequence.InsertRange(counter * 8, numBin);
            foreach(int b in sequence)
            {
                Console.Write(b);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            counter++;
        }
        if(step == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(0);
            return;
        }
        for(int i = sequence.Count; i >= 0; i--)
        {   
            if(i % step == 1)
            {
                sequence.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("List count = {0}", sequence.Count);
        if(sequence.Count % 8 != 0)
        {
            int padding = 8 - (sequence.Count % 8);
            for(int i = 0; i < padding; i++)
            {
                sequence.Add(0);
            }
        }
        foreach(int b in sequence)
        {
            Console.Write(b);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for(int i = 7, power = 0, y = 0; y < sequence.Count; i--, y++, power++)
        {
            number = number + (sequence[i]) * ToPower(2, power); 
            if(i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", number);
                sequence.RemoveRange(0, 8);
                foreach(int b in sequence)
                {
                    Console.Write(b);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
                number = 0;
                i = 7;
                y = 0;
                power = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    static int[] ToBin(int number)
    {
        var binSequence = new int[8];
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0; number /= 2, i--)
        {
            if(number % 2 == 0 || (number == 0 && i >= 0))
            {
                binSequence[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                binSequence[i] = 1;
            }
        }
        return binSequence;
    }

    static int ToPower(int number, int power)
    {
        int numberReturn = number;
        if(power == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if(number == 1)
        {
            return number;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < power - 1; i++)
        {
            numberReturn = numberReturn * number;
        }
        return numberReturn;
    }
}
```

Now, there are a couple of extra print lines so you can see the binary numbers coming up as you input numbers.
 In short my program converts the numbers to lists containing only '1' and '0' and then removes values from this list according to my formula.
 My main question is why is:

```
sequence.Count
```

returning 22, when there are obviously 24 '1's inside the list.
 Test it with the following input: `3,19,255,255,255`.
 The Result will be: `255, 254, 252`, while the correct output would be `255, 255, 252`.

It is happening, because of this code:

```
if(sequence.Count % 8 != 0)
{
    int padding = 8 - (sequence.Count % 8);
    for(int i = 0; i < padding; i++)
    {
        sequence.Add(0);
    }
}
```

Because the `sequence.Count` is 22 ( why? ) the condition is true and the following for loop is replacing my last two '1's with 2 zeros.
 Which is causing the wrong output.
 So back to the point.
 Why is `sequence.Count` equal to 22, when there are 24 '1's in the list.

Sorry, if it is a bit long and confusing, but I posted the whole code, because I have no idea what and how could be interfering to cause this issue.

Comment: It should be obvious to you that `myList.Count` is returning _exactly_ the number of elements in the list. Your issue is that you do not expect that number of elements to be in the list.

Comment: `“myList.Count” is less then the amount of elements inside the list` Have you inspected the list through the debugger to see that there is 24 items instead of 22?

Comment: Try to insert this: `Console.WriteLine("List count before looping = {0}", sequence.Count);` before this line: `for(int i = sequence.Count; i >= 0; i--)`, you'll see that the `for` loop is removing 2 elements from `sequence`. The reason is explained in @Ed T's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You are removing two items from the list in this code:

```
for(int i = sequence.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{   
    if(i % step == 1)
    {
        sequence.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

With the example input you gave, `sequence.RemoveAt` is being called when i == 20 and when i == 1.  There were 24 items, then you removed 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Duly noted: A whole day into programming affects my basic calculus. The list count and if conditions are both performing properly. After another hour of testing I realized that the problem was that I need to set both 'y' and 'i' to - 1 value, because they are incrementing instantly by 1 when they hit the for loop. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: glad you got it figured out.  Please accept my answer if it was helpful.